# Creating custom "list" attributes

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create functions for the property list. How do you create the attribute function for something like this?

```
list([1,2,3,4,5]).even()
```

should return:

```
[2,4]
```

The method should be easy but I am having trouble associating the function with the predefined object list.

Comment: You can't. Python doesn't allow this.

Comment: Don't put links to secondary questions that only appear behind a login wall. If you have another question, then ask it.

Comment: Do you want to change the original list?

Comment: No, i want the function call above to work. Apparently there is a solution but, based on the posts below, i do not think it is possible. The above is one test code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add methods or attributes to any of the built-in objects.  This is by design.

Instead, you can create your own list type that is derived from the built-in one:

```
class MyList(list):
    def even(self):
        return [x for x in self if x % 2 == 0]
```

Demo:

```
>>> class MyList(list):
...     def even(self):
...         return [x for x in self if x % 2 == 0]
... 
>>> MyList([1,2,3,4,5]).even()
[2, 4]
```

For more information, see [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) in the documentation, specifically the section on [Inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance).

Comment: Or `self[:] = (x for x in self if not x % 2)` to change the original list,

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - Well, the OP said he wanted to have `even()` return `[2, 4]`.  If the method mutated the list, then it should probably return `None` instead to be consistent with `list.sort()` or `list.reverse()`.  That's why I made it return a new list.

Answer (score 4):

You can't monkeypatch built in objects in Python like you can in Ruby. You'd have to build a new object, inherit `list`, and put your method on that.

```
class MyList(list):
    def even(self):
        return [num for num in self if num % 2 == 0]

MyList([1,2,3,4,5]).even()
```